# Arabic characters do not display correctly when saving and reopening text file

Tags: character-encoding, notepad, arabic

When I save a text file with arabic letters from Notepad, they do not show correctly after reopening. Instead it shows `??????`.

Example, this is my file in Notepad:

[image]

Then after saving, closing and reopening the file:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your question is why does this happen, is because Notepad cannot display all the characters, regardless of their Unicode. Arabic characters come into this category.

To solve your problem, you need to save the file with the encoding of **UTF-8**. Choose: **File - Save as** . From there you can enter the file name and the mentioned encoding.

Comment: how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Check my edit to the answer.